# Multiple files upload with cocoon and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, carrierwave, capybara-webkit, cocoon-gem

I have issue with testing uploading multiple files with `capybara` using `cocoon`. How can I find all fields with `id: "image"` and attach to each of them file?

Here is my test code:

```
  click_link "Add photo"
  wait_for_ajax

  click_link "Add photo"
  wait_for_ajax


  page.all(:class, '.attach_fileds').each do |el|
    attach_file( el, "#{Rails.root}/spec/assets/example.jpg")
  end

  click_button "Add"

  expect(Post.count).to eq(1)
  expect(Post.last.images.size).to eq(2)
```

Error message: 
`Unable to find file field #<Capybara::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/div/div/div/form[@id='new_post']/div[@id='educations']/div[1]/input[@id='image']">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id, since thats illegal html. Based on your sample code (not sure what the :class selector is so guessing) you really want every element with a class of 'attach_field'. `#attach_file` doesn't take an element as its first parameter, instead it takes the name, id, or label text of the element. Since you already have the elements you can just call #set on each of them

```
page.all(:css, '.attach_field').each do |el
  el.set "path of file to upload"
end
```

If instead you just want every file input you could do

```
page.all(:css, 'input[type="file"]').each do |el|
  el.set "path of file to upload")
end
```

Also note that you need something between `click_button "Add"` and  `expect(Post.count).to eq(1)` to make the test wait for the submission to finish -  something like

```
expect(page).to have_text('Image Uploaded') # if the page adds text when image is uploaded
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/some_new_path') # if the page url changes after the upload is complete
```